# Stripe + Clickfunnels and webhooks

Tags: php, laravel

I've recently integrated webhooks into my stripe account.
I've also integrated a clickfunnels page. After a charge.successful event has been triggered from my landing page I'm expecting to get some POST to my webhook.

```
<?php namespace Laravel\Cashier;

use Exception;
use Stripe_Event;
use Stripe_Customer;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Person;
use Order;
use OrderItem;
use Item;


class WebhookController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Handle a Stripe webhook call.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */


    public function handleWebhook()
    {

        $payload = $this->getJsonPayload();

        try {
            $var = Stripe_Event::retrieve($payload['id']);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        if (!$this->eventExistsOnStripe($payload['id'])) {
            return "doesn't exist onstripe";
        }

        $method = 'handle' . studly_case(str_replace('.', '_', $payload['type']));

        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            return $this->{$method}($payload);
        } else {
            return $this->missingMethod();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verify with Stripe that the event is genuine.
     *
     * @param  string $id
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function eventExistsOnStripe($id)
    {

        try {
            return !is_null(Stripe_Event::retrieve($id));
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            return false;
        }
    }

    protected function handleChargeSucceeded(array $payload)
    {
        return true
    }

    /**
     * Handle a failed payment from a Stripe subscription.
     *
     * @param  array $payload
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function handleInvoicePaymentFailed(array $payload)
    {
        if ($this->tooManyFailedPayments($payload)) {
            $billable = $this->getBillable($payload['data']['object']['customer']);

            if ($billable) $billable->subscription()->cancel();
        }

        return new Response('Webhook Handled', 200);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the invoice has too many failed attempts.
     *
     * @param  array $payload
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function tooManyFailedPayments(array $payload)
    {
        return $payload['data']['object']['attempt_count'] > 3;
    }

    /**
     * Get the billable entity instance by Stripe ID.
     *
     * @param  string $stripeId
     * @return \Laravel\Cashier\BillableInterface
     */
    protected function getBillable($stripeId)
    {
        return App::make('Laravel\Cashier\BillableRepositoryInterface')->find($stripeId);
    }

    /**
     * Get the JSON payload for the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getJsonPayload()
    {


        return (array)json_decode(Request::getContent(), true);
    }

    /**
     * Handle calls to missing methods on the controller.
     *
     * @param  array $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function missingMethod($parameters = array())
    {
        return new Response;
    }

}
```

I have also put code on [this link](https://pastebin.com/hSRbjCAp) as it contains too many methods.

But this doesn't appear to be the case.

When I go to Stripe event logs I can see that only the clickfunnel webhooks were triggered and not mine.. How to fix this so I can trigger both my webhook and clickfunnels?

Comment: Please share the relevant code of your integration.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hSRbjCAp
The webhook code isn't the issue. I'm not receiving any POSTS to my server. And when I simulate the request using curl my webhook is fine. It's just in the stripe developer console, the webhook is only configured for ClickFunnels not for my own webhook, for that particular ClickFunnel event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click funnel sends JSON data not POST so you might need to use something like this to receive the data from ClickFunnels:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, You solved a very complex issue for me